# SCIM 2.0 implementations with good documentation

Tags: scim

I just started exploring scim2.0. Following link provides me different implementations of scim2.0.
http://www.simplecloud.info/

Can some one suggest me, which one is easy to learn and has good documentation. It is helpful, if you suggest me some good tutorials about scim.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're interested in a .NET / OWIN-based open source solution, please take a look at https://github.com/PowerDMS/Owin.Scim. Documentation is limited as the project is still in alpha, but there is a WIKI and sample project to help you get started.

Note: I am the lead developer on this project.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually I am looking for Java based implementations..Any suggestions....

Comment: If you're looking at open source, the options seem rather limited for compliant SCIM 2 servers on any tech stack. The SCIM website lists some projects in which most seem dead or offer minimal compliancy. The most feature-complete Java code base I've looked at is https://github.com/Kumiq/kumiq-identity, although I've never tried it.

Comment: @HariKrishna: UnboundID is working on a SCIM 2 Java SDK and there are plans to release the SDK most likely before the end of June. Watch the https://github.com/UnboundID/ space. I hope this helps.

Comment: FYI. The UnboundID SCIM 2 Java SDK has been released to the public - see https://github.com/UnboundID/scim2

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a reference Java/EE implementation of SCIM2 you can checkout [Apache Directory SCIMple](https://github.com/apache/directory-scimple.git) or [SCIM 2 SDK | PingIdentity](https://github.com/pingidentity/scim2)